# User information as global var on front-end

Tags: javascript

- What is the best way to prevent an end-user of a web application from
  manipulating front-end JavaScript global variables and other runtime
  objects?
- What are the best steps I can take to minimize security
  vulnerabilities and tampering on the part of a 'bad' user?
- Whether they are authenticated by the application or not?

Comment: You can't stop the user to do anything client side. You have to handle the security server-side.

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The best solution against users tampering with global variables, is to not have global variables. But that's more of a good practice thing than a security thing.

You seem to have a small misunderstanding about how client-side code work. **Client-side code runs on the client. You have no control over the client, your user does**. You give my browser code, and kindly ask it to run it as you intend it to. The browser has absolutely no obligation to actually run the code as you intend it to.

From a security viewpoint, never assume your client-side code ever ran as you intended it to. Even Curt's suggested can trivially be overcome with the use of a debugger and the developer console.

**NEVER rely on user input. NEVER rely on client-side validation. NEVER send any sensitive information about any other user to the client**. Any information you send can and will be used against you.

Answer (score 2):

In terms of security vulnerabilities, front-end is not the place to be concerning yourself with this. **Javascript won't protect you against this**.

There's also not much you can do to prevent users from manipulating global variables. They're accessible right there in the console.

I would question why you are cluttering the global namespace with variables however.

The best option here would be to create a **[Revealing Module Pattern](http://curtistimson.co.uk/js/mixing-revealing-module-and-singleton-javascript-patterns/)** which creates *private* variables.

```
var MyFunction = function(){

   var _ = {
      Init: function(){

      },
      PrivateVariable: "foo bar"
   }

   return {
      Init: _.Init
   }

}();
```

However this is used more for **encapsulation** rather than for security benefits. **There is no security with client-side**. This should all be handled server-side.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Very true!